# Using Google App Engine development server as a production server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I'm not sure if is it usefull to use GAE dev server on my hardware instead of Glassfish or JBoss/Wildfly. Google provides easy-to-use endpoints API and Objectify, both they making software developing much easier (especially Objectify) and both seems stable and multifunctional.
But I'm not sure about their performance and reliability.
What disadvantages of using it on a local machine instead of deploying to Google?

Comment: Using something explicitly called a dev server as something other than a dev server sounds like asking for trouble.

Comment: Perhaps refer to this (although it is old; things may have changed): https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1927903 "One thing not mentioned is the development server slowness and need to constantly restart it. The live website actually ends up being much faster than the development site on your machine. Apparently, this is due to the fact that the development server is single threaded."

Comment: Not to mention that you lose all of the automated management provided by running on Google infrastructure (e.g. creating new instances in response to load; restarting dead instances; resilience to local datacenter issues etc)

Comment: When thinking about hosting an app engine application yourself, AppScale and CapeDwarf should be on your list of things to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Development server emulates the behavior of the production environment. For example, all data is stored as a String, instead of actual entities that you put to and get from the Datastore. Obviously, this is not scalable and orders of magnitude slower.

If you are not using the Datastore or Memcache, and you don't need the scalability/capacity management that App Engine provides, you can write your code as a Java program and run it on any computer, including your own.

If you use the Datastore, but do not need scalability/capacity management, you can also write a simple Java app and use gcloud API to access the Datastore (as well as Cloud Storage and other services) from your own computer.